# Header not redirect and not display error

Tags: php, redirect, header

2 days ago I switched hosting and I have problems that did not exist before.

I have the code:

```
$slug = html_entity_decode($_POST['slug']);

[...]

$insertGames = "UPDATE `jogos` SET [...]  WHERE id='$id' ";
    mysql_query($insertGames) or die(mysql_error());

header( "Location:./?a=jogos&b=edit&slug=".$slug."&msg=". base64_encode('Sucess msg!')."&e=s");
```

If I print, the URL is displayed correctly.. The Mysql data is added normally.. Yes, I have html code before, but this are not problem before. :/

AH, i tried get all error, but continued without error and without redirect.

Thanks! :)

Comment: *PSA:* The `mysql_*` functions are [deprecated in PHP 5.5](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.databases.php#faq.databases.mysql.deprecated). It is not recommended for writing new code as it will prevent you from upgrading in the future. Instead, use either [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) and [be a better PHP Developer](http://jason.pureconcepts.net/2012/08/better-php-developer/).

Comment: Have you put `error_reporting(-1); ini_set('display_errors', 'On');` at the top of your script?

Comment: I tried now and no problem with the headers!

Comment: also note that Location should be a full url not a relative one

Comment: @Dagon I tried with full url too. :/

Answer (score 0):

This means your previous configuration had output [buffering](http://php.net/manual/en/outcontrol.configuration.php) turned on. Now it is off.  You can override this value with a `.htaccess` file with the following line

```
php_value output_buffering 1
```

Comment: I got a 500 error on all my pages with this.. :(
Have other method?

Comment: you have to get the actual error from the error log. its possible you missed some permission along the way

Comment: [Fri Jul 26 00:05:13 2013] [alert] [client xxx] /home/retroplu/public_html/.htaccess: Invalid command 'php_value', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration

Comment: then your system doesn't allow change from htaccess.

Comment: And now!? Have solution?

Comment: you have to either A talk to your hosting company or B. remove all the html before the header, or C use ob_start()